# Do 12V MR16 LED bulbs contain active components?

Tags: led

I was wondering if, unlike GU10 (230V AC) LEDs, GU5.3/MR16 (12V DC) LED bulbs typically contain any active voltage regulating components?

[image: MR16 led]

Or do they directly connect the LEDs to the 12V line so there is no chance for harmonics/flicker/etc. (aside from the 12V supply itself of course)?

Comment: Since LEDs are current driven devices there must be some way to limit the current. Which we can not tell without taking one apart.

Comment: Most have SMPSes inside but if you look hard enough, you may find some purely passive.

Comment: @winny s/look hard enough/buy the cheapest one/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MR16 bulbs are most commonly 12VAC powered, dimmable, and use active components.  A true Halogen retro-fit MR16 LED lamps are compatible with ELVT and ELV dimmers

[image][image][image]

**LM3444 MR16 driver**
[image]

**LM3401 MR16 driver**
[image]

> SSL MR16 lamps compatibility concerns with ELVT and ELV dimmers (true
>   retro-fit)
>   Electronic transformers modulate (PWM) the input AC voltage with a
>   frequency of 35 kHz to150 kHz. This waveform is step-down from 120V or
>   230V (typical) to 12VAC with a transformer. The higher switching
>   frequency allows for the smaller magnetic components, and the overall
>   smaller design. As mentioned earlier, the electronic transformer is a
>   self driven resonant half bridge topology.  The self resonance
>   half-bridge topology requires the converter to have a minimal load at
>   all times to function properly. Common minimum loads for ELV dimmers
>   are from 6W – 12W depending on manufacture, and maximum power rating
>   of the ELVT. With traditional Halogen lamps, the minimal load is of no
>   concern, common Halogen MR16 lamps use about 50W of power per lamp.
>   These lamps are very inefficient, and 10W of Halogen power produces
>   very little light.
>
> With the current efficacy of the LEDs above 100 lumens per watt, 6W of
>   SSL power is equivalent to about 40W to  50W of Halogen power. One can
>   quickly see the compatibility issue of SSL MR16 lamps and the ELVT’s.
>   If the  output power of the ELVT reduces below the minimum
>   requirement, the ELV dimmer will stop operating. The  turning on, and
>   off of the ELVT will cause visible flicker from the SSL MR16 lamp, and
>   could also cause reliability  issues with the lamp or ELVT.
>
> Source: LM3401 MR16 Reference Designs for Non-Dimming & Dimming LED Applications